# Как создать свой тюнингованный SeekBar на андроид?

Tags: android, listview, java

Всем доброе утро!
Возник вопрос, над которым я бьюсь уже вторые сутки, но у меня пока толком ничего не получается, поэтому решил обратиться к Вам, уважаемые форумчане.
Так вот вопрос.
[image]
На рисунке выше я представил свой SeekBar в двух положениях.
В положении нуль на нем расположен `ImageView` что слева, два `TextView` тоже слева дальше от `ImageView` и еще один `TextView` справа. Это в положении когда `SeekBar` никто не дергает!
Теперь когда пользователь начинает его перетаскивать `ImageView` становиться невидимым на его месте появляется `TextView`, а `TextView` что были слева начинают перемещаться вместе с ползунком SeekBar'а. Еще необходимо установить ограничение в перемещении ползунка и программно отключить возможность перемещения щелчком, то ес ть оставить только перетаскивание ползунка. Да главное возможно ли это реализовать стандартными средствами и как?
Буду рад любой помощи!
Спасибо!

Comment: Я знаю одно, что нужно создать Compaund компонент, но загвоздка вся в том что я не могу объеденить SeekBar с ImageView! На iPhone знакомы это дело довольно просто, как он говорит, реализовал! А вот как это сделать на андроид! Неужели никто не сталкивался?

Comment: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: @gorets спасибо конечно, но такиt SeekBar'ы я делал и не раз. Они не представляют никакой особой сложности, а вот тот вариант о котором я говорю можно реализовать как я понимаю только при создании Compaund компонента.

Comment: Неужели никто не делал подобного?((

Comment: Что по поводу того, чтобы подойти с другой стороны. Я не вижу оссобенностей, из-за котрых требуется делать оформление SeekBar. Я бы попробовал использовать только ивенты SeekBarа для изменения размеров кастомного контрола. Имхо - сикбар прозрачен и дает только инфу -> по инфе меняем что угодно.

Comment: Ничего не выходит! Выглядит все очень и очень убого. Может есть библиотеки с подобными компонентами?

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку могу предложить. Делаете нужную разметку + SeekBar с прозрачным фоном и нужным вам бегунком. При обработке движения бегунка в нужном положении меняете разметку, показываете/скрываете нужные view и т.д.

Comment: должен быть полностью кастомный элемент, на нем же должны цифры менятся

Comment: Аня большое спасибо! Вы открыли мне глаза! А если серьезно, Вы думаете до этого никто не додумался? Прочтите мои комменты!

Comment: @Gorets, а в чем проблема? Цифры на подложке, которая не просто фон, а как раз compaund, со своей разметкой и т.д.

Comment: @vanyamelikov, как грубо.

Comment: Я не в обиду! Просто что то не выходит такая реализация! Я пока отложил эту проблему, но мысль така что надо отказать полностью от сик бара а его свойства присвоить другому элементу(может TextView или ImageView).